# Django/cookiecutter-django Error: "AttributeError: 'Path' object has no attribute 'endswith''" with manage.py makemigrations

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cookiecutter-django

I have been trying to set up Django with a cookiecutter-django project 
with  cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django.git
and I get this error output when I run `./manage.py makemigrations` at the end.

My python version in the virturalenv is Python 3.5.2

This is the tail of console output and not from a file.
Stack overflow doesn't allow me to post all of the long error output without more of other text.

```
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 156, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1588, in contribute_to_class
    self.remote_field.through = create_many_to_many_intermediary_model(self, cls)
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1057, in create_many_to_many_intermediary_model
    'verbose_name': _('%(from)s-%(to)s relationship') % {'from': from_, 'to': to},
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 192, in __mod__
    return str(self) % rhs
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 156, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 79, in gettext
    return _trans.gettext(message)
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 285, in gettext
    _default = _default or translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 198, in translation
    _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 99, in __init__
    self._add_local_translations()
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 151, in _add_local_translations
    translation = self._new_gnu_trans(localedir)
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 123, in _new_gnu_trans
    fallback=use_null_fallback,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gettext.py", line 428, in translation
    mofiles = find(domain, localedir, languages, all=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gettext.py", line 396, in find
    mofile = os.path.join(localedir, lang, 'LC_MESSAGES', '%s.mo' % domain)
  File "/root/painlesslanguage/painlesslanguageenv/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 84, in join
    elif not path or path.endswith(sep):
AttributeError: 'Path' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

I left the TIME_ZONE cookiecutter-django setup option blank if that matters.

Comment: What line/file is this on?

Comment: I updated the post after a re-install.
console output

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a difficult error to fix or even debug.
some users have gotten this error when they have not included the static url properly in settings.py of left a trailing comma in the INSTALLED_APPS declaration.

however i got this error just when i switched a python version.
I ended up somehow solving it (at the time) by reinstalling python and relinking pyenv python to brew.

however, now its returned. there must be a way to debug this.
all the stacktrace points to files in the python install or only to the settings file. but if your settings file looks fine, its really hard to know how to fix it. After checking your settings.py INSTALLED_APPS (to check there are no trailing commas) id suggest reinstalling python and see if that helps.

if that doesnt work, then what helped me was printing out the apps being installed. to do this you will have to add print lines into the python/django code where the errors are thrown. as by default this info isnt being sent to the application layer, though it should be. these will be removed if you ever change the py install again. so its kind of a temperoray/local way to help u debug. really the framework should send the name info if it fails to import an app. by adding these lines i found what was going wrong with my import.